# stored proceure to find the radius using pair of coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, stored-procedures

I have tried to implement store procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE FindRadius(IN stop_lat float,IN stop_lng float,IN lat float,IN lng float,OUT radius float)
    BEGIN 
    declare R INT DEFAULT 6371;
    declare dLat float;
    declare dLon float;
    declare a float;
    declare c float;
    dLat = RADIANS(stop_lat-lat);  
    dLon = RADIANS(stop_lng-lng); 
     a =  SIN(dLat/2) * SIN(dLat/2) +COS(RADIANS(stop_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(dLon/2) *SIN(dLon/2); 
     c = 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a),SQRT(1-a)); 
    SET radius = R * c *1000; 
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

It is throwing error saying that  You have an error in your SQL syntax;

`RADIANS(stop_lat-lat); dLon = RADIANS(stop_lng-lng); a = SIN(dLat/2) * SI' at line 8`

I have no idea why this error is comming can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not do:

```
dLat = ....
```

it should be:

```
SET dLat = RADIANS(stop_lat-lat);  
SET dLon = RADIANS(stop_lng-lng); 
SET a =  SIN(dLat/2) * SIN(dLat/2) +COS(RADIANS(stop_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(dLon/2) *SIN(dLon/2); 
SET c = 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a),SQRT(1-a));
```

Comment: i have called that stored proceure but it is throwing error do i have send out also as a parameter like null or 0

Comment: @DynamicDeveloper Please look at these examples: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx